# Office 365 Multi Geo - Issue with fetching PreferredDataLocation property for a user from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to fetch `PreferredDataLocation` (PDL) for a user from Azure Active Directory.

I used Graph v1.0 but do not receive PDL value in the response:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{upn}?$select=preferredDataLocation
```

But when I use Graph Beta, I receive PDL value in the response:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{upn}?$select=preferredDataLocation
```

Does that mean that fetching PDL is not supported in Microsoft Graph v1.0?

I also tried using Microsoft Graph SDK, but there is no property exposed for getting PDL.

Is there a way we can fetch PDL using MS Graph SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PreferredDataLocation` property of a `User` is only returned/supported by the `/beta` endpoints. Since the SDKs currently only support the production API, `PreferredDataLocation` isn't exposed in the object model.

Once this feature makes it into v1.0, subsequent builds of the SDK should include it. If there is an unreasonable delay in a new SDK build, you can also request that it be added. From the [SDK docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f807196101e20d30fbc8628206a2eb5850334a92/CONTRIBUTING.md#when-new-features-are-added-to-the-library):

> #### When new features are added to the library
>
> Generation happens as part of a manual process that occurs once a significant change or set of changes has been added to the Graph. This may include:
>
> - A new workload comes to v1.0 of Graph (Microsoft Teams, Batching, etc.)
> - There is a significant addition of functionality (Delta Queries, etc.)
>
> However, this is evaluated on a case-by-case basis. If the library is missing v1.0 Graph functionality that you wish to utilize, please [file an issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues).

Comment: Now available in the beta SDK: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta